# Conversion into Polar Co-ordinates.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Can someone please hint me as how to solve this category of questions as I am novice in it.

[image]

Can second part be done by simply finding the area of the triangle?

Comment: One cannot do it from just knowing  the area of a triangle. Note that we are integrating $xy\,dx\,dy$. not just $dx\,dy$.

Comment: The area of the triangle would not work because of the $xy$ in the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any method: By **symmetry** the integral is $0$.

Comment: Can you hint something as how to set limits in polar co-ordiantes?

Comment: @Mathematics $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$ from the diagram shown. Now just get $r$ in terms of $\theta$ using some trig.

Comment: It  is a little different $\theta=0$ to $\pi/2$ than $\theta=\pi/2$ to $\pi$. Let's do the first. We have $y=-x+1$ so $r\sin\theta=-r\cos\theta+1$. and therefore $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}$. Of course polar coordinates are a lousy way to do the integral. If one refuses to use symmetry, rectangular coordinates are the way to go.

Comment: So we will have to write two integrals? First from 0 to pi/2 and then from pi/2 to pi and take r accordingly?

Comment: We *should* write two integrals. But one can use a (useless) trick to write it as a single integral. For in the second half $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\sin\theta-\cos\theta}$. But $\cos\theta$ is negative in this interval, so if we write $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\sin\theta+|\cos\theta|}$ we will be right in both parts.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
Basic trigonometry tells us
$$x=r\cos(\theta)$$
$$y=r\sin(\theta)$$
$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$
So substituting these values will help find (a). Also for (a), keep note of the bounds for $r$ and $\theta$ when setting up the double integral. The bounds will most likely be the more difficult part.

For (b), they say *any method*, so area of a triangle would be valid for an empty integral. However, it is asking for the integral of $xy$ instead, so there will be different "weightings" based on where in the triangle you are. You're computing the mass of an object that isn't uniform, so actually computing the double integral will be necessary (Or you can split it between the left and the right triangles, and use the insight mentioned in the below answer).